# How Pundit passes current_user to authorize method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

`Pundit`'s `authorize` takes 3 arguments, but in the controller you just need to pass 2, current_user is passed automatically. How is `current_user` passed?
I looked at Pundit's code, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [pundit readme](https://github.com/varvet/pundit/blob/0e3a11cf3ee0dd914babc989dbc6ff7f61ec8e77/README.md):

> The first argument is a user. In your controller, Pundit will call the current_user method to retrieve what to send into this argument

From [pundit.rb](https://github.com/varvet/pundit/blob/ac2a25d93ccd044ac3ea777a70ffd5e31db10d3a/lib/pundit.rb#L269) file:

```
def pundit_user
  current_user
end
```